# Penalties for cashing out on a SIMPLE IRA early

Tags: united-states, taxes, retirement, penalty, simple-ira

I want to know what are the penalties that an individual will face if they withdraw on a SIMPLE IRA outside of a hardship distribution?

(Additionally) I noticed in another post someone mentioned a '2-year rule' as well. If there is such a thing, how does it factor into this equation?

Comment: The standard penalty for early non-hardship withdrawal of any (non-basis) amount from a Traditional IRA or earnings from a Roth IRA is 10% of the amount withdrawn in addition to income tax on the amount. Do you have any reason to believe that withdrawals from a SIMPLE IRA have different penalties? Also could you include a link to the posting that mentions a '2-year rule' so that everyone reading this is on the same page?

Comment: I suppose I should add if there are any differences as I'm unaware that all IRAs follow the same guidelines when it comes to penalties. Here's the link to the mention of a '2-year rule' on SIMPLE IRAs: http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/7848/options-for-a-simple-ira-when-leaving-a-job-leave-as-is-or-roll-it-over

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 2 year rule means that the penalty will be 25% in addition to your ordinary income tax rates, not the standard 10%.

Other than that its exactly the same as a traditional IRA.

Info at the IRS Q&A [What are the tax consequences when amounts are distributed from a SIMPLE IRA?](http://www.irs.gov/Retirement-Plans/Retirement-Plans-FAQs-regarding-SIMPLE-IRA-Plans#distributions)